# SQL for joining different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I have the following tables :

[image]

[image]

I want to write a Select Statment that show the following result

[image]

I Tried to Join/ Union/Union All the two table but I dont get the desird output. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: How is the second table related to your problem? You need pivot of some kind, no joins and no union. The solution depends on your Oracle version, which you should always include in your questions.

Comment: please paste data as text,it helps  in testing and also helps people who have images blocked

Comment: I tried to use pivot but I' new to it so i didnt get the output I want

Answer (score 0):

```
select
 'group_a' as groupname
, max( case classname when 'C123' then group_a else null end)  as c123
, max( case classname when 'C456' then group_a else null end)  as c456
from table1
union all
select
 'group_b' as groupname
, max( case classname when 'C123' then group_b else null end)  as c123
, max( case classname when 'C456' then group_b else null end)  as c456
from table1
union all
select
 'group_d' as groupname
, max( case classname when 'C123' then group_d else null end)  as c123
, max( case classname when 'C456' then group_d else null end)  as c456
from table1
union all
select
 'group_e' as groupname
, max( case classname when 'C123' then group_e else null end)  as c123
, max( case classname when 'C456' then group_e else null end)  as c456
from table1
```